# Angular ui-select2 directive doesn't work with AngularJS Validation

Tags: angularjs, directive, jquery-select2

I have scoured the internet trying to figure out why the proprietary AngularJS validation is not working when using jQuery.Select2 and the `ui-select2` directive - is it a bug??

Edit: ok I've discovered it is only tagging inputs this is occurring, my Select drop downs and text inputs are working fine.

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/ftEHu/

Html:

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    userType: <input ui-select2="version1" class="input-xlarge" type="hidden" name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required</span><br>
    <tt>userType = {{userType}}</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}} wtf???????!!!</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}} huh????</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}} | please hand me a gun :)</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm.$error.REQUIRED = {{!!myForm.$error.REQUIRED}}</tt><br>
   </form>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives']);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.userType = '';
  $scope.version1 = {
      tags : null
  };    
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe there's a problem in how select2 directive is passing the value between the ngModel and select2 plugin.

In short, when there are no tags selected, the UI's select2 directive will [set the model to []](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/select2/select2.js#L87) (empty array), because that's the default value returned by the select2 plugin on empty multi-select inputs (See [the docs for select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#documentation) Data method)

I'll post an issue on Github to confirm this, but in the meantime here's [a workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/adibih/N2LVP/):

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.userType = null;
  $scope.version1 = {
      tags : null
  };

  $scope.$watch('userType', function(userType){
    if(angular.isArray(userType) && userType.length === 0){
      $scope.userType = '';
    }
  });
}
```

Or you could use this custom 'required-multiple' directive which will take empty array into consideration when validating the model:

```
app.directive('requiredMultiple', function() {
  function isEmpty(value) {
    return angular.isUndefined(value) || (angular.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) || value === '' || value === null || value !== value;
  }

  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      var validator = function(value) {
        if (attr.required && (isEmpty(value) || value === false)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
          return;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('required', true);
          return value;
        }
      };

      ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        validator(ctrl.$viewValue);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: is there a workaround? I'm trying to keep the validation on this project as simple as possible

Comment: Stewie thank you so much. I wish I could thumbs this up 10 times

Comment: Well, your gratitude is worth at least 10 thumbs-ups.

Answer (score 0):

For tagging, the solution I've been using for this issue is setting `ng-minlength="1"` on the input. Seems to work well enough.